# I'm having some issues with my scope identity retrieving a ID from an identity column

Tags: c#, mysql, scope-identity

I'm having some issues with my scope identity retrieving a ID from an identity column.

This is my code:

```
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into oc_manufacturer (name, sort_order) Values(@name, @sort_order);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", sManufacturer);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sort_order", 0);
iManufacturerID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is inside a try catch. and it hits my catch when i step through it at the 2nd last line of code. I am still very new to using this scope identity. Usually i would create a whole new select statement with the same variables as my insert statement. But that is very long so truing to get this right. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I am wrong, but you have marked your question as MySql. In that database system, you retrieve the last inserted autoincrement value with LAST_INSERT_ID() function

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into oc_manufacturer (name, sort_order) 
                    Values(@name, @sort_order);
                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

Also there is no need to call ExecuteNonQuery, the call to ExecuteScalar will work on both statements but will return the value of the last SELECT

Comment: just have to kill some fires then will go try your suggestion. tnx will reply now now when i get back to this. tnx for your quick reply

Comment: ok so i tried your answer. but now it gives me this error:"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred" with Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Change this line `iManufacturerID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` to `iManufacturerID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`